# saving a gravatar to activeStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, gravatar

the following cUrl command in the console, [as per gravatar instructions](http://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) saves an image to the directory it is being called from

```
curl "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ZUETpSoXKBP5VXW4qQnQFIZcLpxh5Ix2?d=identicon" --output 'temp_avatar'
```

However, in order to avoid hitting their server, the goal is to have an action save the output via ActiveStorage

```
class UserPreference < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :identicon
```

and the controller action

```
    if !current_user.user_preference.identicon.present?
      puts 'identicon absent'
      result = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{current_user.virtual_qr_code}.jpg?d=identicon --output '#{current_user.id}_avatar' "))
      puts result.inspect
       current_user.user_preference.identicon.attach(result)
```

the result is a bit perplexing.  The `puts` commands get a response, but a different one from the processing of cUrl straight out

```
identicon absent
#<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>

Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true>
```

What is mistaken in expecting the image output to be different when called via Net::HTTP?
How should this be called to save via ActiveStorage?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've included some of the CURL command into the URL of the Net::HTTP call, and are trying to call this string as an URL
`"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{current_user.virtual_qr_code}.jpg?d=identicon --output '#{current_user.id}_avatar' "` where you actually wanted:
`"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{current_user.virtual_qr_code}.jpg?d=identicon"`

You cannot use --output from within the URL, but you should use the returned body of the GET request instead.

```rb
    if !current_user.user_preference.identicon.present?
      puts 'identicon absent'
      result = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{current_user.virtual_qr_code}.jpg?d=identicon"))
      puts result.inspect #=> Net::HTTPResponse object

      # result.body will return the actual content of the HTTP request, instead of the Net::HTTPResponse object.
      current_user.user_preference.identicon.attach(result.body)
```

Comment: Had tried that, but the inspection of result returns `#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>`  and thus ActiveStorage does not have something valid to handle `Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>`.  However, dropping the output option AND changing the verb to `get` inspects what seems to be image object `"\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\[...]` followed by an error upon `.attach(result)` :  `(ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)`

Comment: Invalid signature implies a data type issue. The returned string has to be processed  `    current_user.user_preference.identicon.attach(
      io: StringIO.new(result),
      filename: some_devised_file_name,
      content_type: 'image/jpeg'
    )`

Comment: You have to `.attach(result.body)` to get the actual HTTP body of the HTTP request. I have updated my answer

Comment: I am afraid not.  the returned result is a string, thus the use of `StringIO`